# how to create json array from python list of oracle queries

Tags: python, sql, json, oracle

I need to generate an json object for each statement that I am executing. This will later be used to serve some tables and charts on a web page but for now I am having difficulty generating the 4 json arrays. Any help is greatly appreciated. Here is my code so far:

```
import json
import requests
import collections
import cx_Oracle as ora
import csv

print "Content-type: application/json"

statements = []

## Prepare umts weekly site_level cqi statement
umts_cqi_site_stmt = """SELECT PERIOD_END, ZONE_ID, USID, SITE_ID, ENGINEERING_NOTES, SITE_RANK, U_CQI_SCORE, 
                        TOTAL_3GCQI, U_DROPPED_CALL_RATE, ACCESSIBILITY, U_PS_RETAINABILITY, PS_RAN_ACCESSIBILITY, U_RAN_THROUGHPUT
                        FROM moks.umts_weekly_cqi_drilldown"""

## Prepare lte weekly site_level cqi statement
lte_cqi_site_stmt = """SELECT PERIOD_END, ZONE_ID, USID, SITE_ID, ENGINEERING_NOTES, SITE_RANK, LCQI_SCORE, TOTAL_LCQI, 
                       TNOL_CSFB, ERAB_RETANABILITY, RAN_DATA_ACCESSIBILITY, IRAT, DL_UE_THROUGHPUT
                       FROM moks.lte_weekly_cqi_drilldown"""

## Prepare volte weekly site_level cqi statement
volte_cqi_site_stmt = """SELECT PERIOD_END, ZONE_ID, USID, SITE_ID, ENGINEERING_NOTES, SITE_RANK, VOLTE_SCORE, TOTAL_VOLTECQI, 
                         DROP_CALLS_CORE_CDR, CNOV_CALLS_NOT_ON_VOLTE, ACCESS_FAILURES_RAN_NODE_STATS, DROP_CALLS_RAN_NODE_STATS
                         FROM moks.volte_weekly_cqi_drilldown"""                

## Prepare weekly market cqi statement
cqi_market_weekly_stmt = """SELECT TO_CHAR(WEEK,'YYYY-MM-DD') WEEK, MARKET, METRICNAME, CQI, YELLOW_THRESHOLD, GREEN_THRESHOLD
                            FROM moks.market_level_cqi_weekly 
                            ORDER BY METRICNAME, WEEK, MARKET"""

statements = [umts_cqi_site_stmt,lte_cqi_site_stmt,volte_cqi_site_stmt,cqi_market_weekly_stmt]

connection = ora.connect('---------------------')
print "We are connected!"

cursor = connection.cursor()
for stmt in statements:
    cursor.execute(stmt)

rows = cursor.fetchall()

json_output = json.dumps(rows)
print json_output

print "done"
```

Comment: What are you getting for an output/error?  How is it different from what you're expecting?  What do you have to work with for data?

Comment: There is not any error. I just am unable to figure out how to generate the json object from the results of the queries.